# Spring Boot Modify Default JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a REST controller that returns a list of products like so:

**Current output**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Money market"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Certificate of Deposit"
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "name":"Personal Savings"
   }
]
```

In order to get things working with our JS grid library, I need the modify the response to look like:

**Desired output**

```
{ "data" :
   [  
       {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"Money market"
       },
       {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"Certificate of Deposit"
       },
       {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"Personal Savings"
       }
    ]
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllProducts() {

  List<Product> result = productService.findAll();
  return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

Is there an easy way to modify the JSON response using native Spring libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put result object into a Map with key "data" and value as result.

`map.put("data", result);`

Then return the map object from the rest method.

`return ResponseEntity.ok(map)`;

Answer (score 5):

Using [org.json](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) library:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("data", result);
```

> The put methods add or replace values in an object.